# How to interpret an unsigned integer as a signed one and vice versa in Crystal?

Tags: crystal-lang

In C, to interpret the very bits of an integer as that of an integer of another type (not casting the integer, but rather using the same bits for a different type), one can do this:

```c
uint8_t x = 0xFF;
int8_t y = *((int8_t*) &x);
```

The best I can come up with in Crystal is this, but it's highly unsafe, and `y` only lives as long as `x` does (and in fact, you can't reuse the same variable).

```
x = 0xFF_u8
y = pointerof(x).as(Int8*).value
```

Is there an **idiomatic and safe way to do this conversion in Crystal?** I wouldn't mind the value being copied.

(And yeah, you betcha I'm writing an emulator in Crystal!)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`unsafe_as`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.35.1/Object.html#unsafe_as(type:T.class)forallT-instance-method), for example:

```
x = 0xFF_u8            # 255 : Uint8
y = x.unsafe_as(Int8)  # -1  : Int8
```

But as the name says you have be careful when using it. To quote the documentation:

> This method is unsafe because it behaves unpredictably when the given type doesn't have the same bytesize as the receiver, or when the given type representation doesn't semantically match the underlying bytes.

If you want to detect overloads, prefer [`to_i8`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.35.1/Int32.html#to_i8:Int8-instance-method).

```
x = 0xFF_u8
z = x.to_i8 # Arithmetic overflow
```

You have to decide whether the first version is safe enough for your use case. While the C code in your question might not be undefined behavior, it should be implementation dependent behavior. That means, it is not portable in a strict sense, but you should get consistent results for a specific architecture. And given that [two's-complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) is now practically a standard, I would expect to see the same behavior on most of today's hardware. The Crystal code should fall into the same category.